# React renderDOM in multiple spots on same page?

Tags: html, reactjs

I want react to render a DOM at multiple spots on my page.  For example, if there's the class (.react-container), I want it to render the react component.

How can I do this if there are multiple spots on the page?

IMPORTANT: ArrayOne amount changes depending on where it's rendered.

```
APP.JS FILE
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
<div className="react-container">
        {
          ArrayOne.map(item=> (
            <div className={
              clsx({
                'card': true,
                'card-visible': state
              })} >
                <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                <p>{item.text}</p>
            </div>
          ))
        }
       
      </div>

</div>
  );
};

INDEX.JS FILE
for (const el of document.querySelectorAll(".react-container")) {
  ReactDOM.render(<App/>, el);
}
```

```
Code above is not running how I would like it to.  It gives me two rows of only 1 card. When it should be 4 cards on row one and 1 card on row two.  Console shows:
run query selector
running (4)
run query selector
running(1)
run query selector
running(1)

When I want it to do.
run query selector
running(4)
run query selector
running(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting code. But i believe you are mixing some stuff.

1. get the layout working first, since seems you are not using React to do the layout.

```
  <div>
    <div className="react-container"></div>
    <div className="react-container"></div>
    <div className="react-container"></div>
    <div className="react-container"></div>
  </div>
```

2. render them into it with your lines.

```
for (const el of document.querySelectorAll(".react-container")) {
  ReactDOM.render(<App/>, el);
}
```

Keep in mind, if you want to use your rest of code, you need to render it into a root, as in a typical React setup.

```
  <div id="root"></div>
```

So pick one approach, either render once, but let react control everything underneath it, or render multiple times. You can't do both.

Comment: if I let react do all the layout (edited code above). Would the answer change? Still having the same issue.

Comment: Should add. ArrayOne, is getting pulled in by backend. It works great alone (its mapping through alll the cards correctly). But with the extra for loop for reeactDom, it's acting not as intended